# Why reference to blog points to same link

Tags: discussion, blog, community-bulletin

On Stackoverflow home page there are two blocks on the right, both pointing to

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/

[image]

Is there a specific reason, can't we just have one and use the other place for something else, rather than duplicate links.

Comment: Sorry, no.  Our anniversary is just that important.

Comment: I mean it's not like the Community Bulletin is static... once a new blog post comes out this won't be an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The top blue image is injected to the sidebar as-is on all sites, they do it for really really important updates or messages, think the last time was when the reputation system changed (e.g. question upvote worth 5 instead of 10 which caused lots of users to lose lots of reputation) so they linked to the announcement with such a cross network banner.
- The Community Bulletin is per-site and can show selected posts from the site's Meta or related blog and I believe moderators can also choose what will appear there. Note that other sites Community Bulletin does not point to the "five years" blog post.

Answer (score 8):

Blog posts and community bulletin links are not questions; therefore, they are exempt from being closed as duplicates.

Also, for crying out loud, **Stack Overflow just turned 5 years old**! It's a pretty big deal you know.

Comment: lol, that is a good enough reason

Comment: I think we need at least three duplicate blocks.  Surely only two will not do.

Answer (score 0):

As much that I understand, One is an Alarm saying: "**Stackoverflow Turned 5, Wish him a happy birthday.** The other one is the latest post on the community blog.

If you want to mark it as duplicate? Read the answer of moderator above. He has a clear view about it and he told that you cannot mark the blogs posts and community bulletins to be closed or to be kept on hold if they are duplicate.

No offense, neither funny but I hope being a developer you must have noticed a slight change in both URLs, `?cb=1` is present at the end of the second link! :D

Comment: it's Community Blog 1, but...? What? :D